# C++ creating an object and using it in the same line

Tags: c++, constructor

I'm fairly new to C++ and was wondering about this:

Suppose I need to create an object x of the class X and call its function foo() which returns
an object y of type Y. I don't need x anymore after I have obtained y.

Currently, I do something like this: (suppose a and b are parameters to X's constructor)

```
X x(a,b);
Y y = x.foo();
```

However, for readability issues, I would like to do these things in a single line. Also, it's pointless to have the name x lying around.

My native programming language is Java, where I would do something like this:

```
Y y = (new X(a,b)).foo();
```

I apologize for asking such a basic question, but my searches delivered nothing, since most of them returned results about the C++ inline keyword, which is completely unrelated to the matter.

Comment: It sounds like you may have a design issue:  why do you need to call `foo` to begin with?  It may be that `foo` is a class member when it would be better served as a standalone function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C++ uses stack-allocation by default. That means you don't have to use new, because variables are not pointers. To solve your problem, only remove the `new`.

```
Y y = X( a, b ).foo();
```

`X( a , b )` is a call to a constructor of `X`, and `.foo()` calls the member function `foo` of the rvalue returned by the ctor.

Note that C++ variables lifetime is linked to variable's scope. That means a variable is initializated at the point of its declaration, and destroyed when the program goes out of its scope.
That means (Regardling in your code) the scope of the rvalue created by the constructor call `X(a , b )` is that sentence (`Y y = X( a, b ).foo();`) only, so the value is destroyed after the end of that sentence. Thats why in general calling ctors in that way is a bad practice.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. I actually tried this, but my ide acted a little glitchy. For some reason it doesn't complain this time whereas it did before. It compiles just fine now :) I probably misplaced a bracket somewhere the first time

Comment: @DaanDisk see the edit, it could help you to understand C++ variables.

Comment: So if y still depends on x this would create a problem? (for example: if y were an iterator over x)

Comment: If y gets a reference to that rvalue, yes that could be a problem, because you could reference a destroyed variable after that sentence.

Answer (score 1):

This compiles for example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Person {

    Person getRelatedPerson () {
        return Person();
    }

    void printAge () {
        std::cout << 5 << std::endl;
    }
};

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Person person;

    person.getRelatedPerson().printAge();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Compiles, but is horribly leaky.

Comment: getRelatedPerson returns a new Person object (not to confuse with allocating a new object using the keyword "new") of whom the printAge member function is called.

Answer (score 0):

Building upon the code samples here, I was curious and went to play a bit.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Person
{
    int age = 5;

    Person()
    {
    };

    Person(int newage) : age(newage)
    {
    };

    Person getNewPerson()
    {
        return Person();
    }

    void printAge()
    {
        std::cout << age << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Person person;
    person.getNewPerson().printAge();       // 5

    Person p2 = Person(6).getNewPerson();
    p2.printAge();                          // 5

    Person p3 = Person(6);
    p3.printAge();                          // 6

    Person(9).getNewPerson().printAge();    // 5

    Person(9).printAge();                   // 9

    return 0;
}
```